# how can I modify text in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that will store contact details of users entered on the system. I am stuck on being able to edit the stored information based on what the user enters. I need to search the text file for the criteria and then edit the 7 lines below the criteria. I am completely stumped, any help would be appreciated. I can post my full code too if that helps.

```
def ChngAddress():
   criteria = input("Enter the last name of the address you wish to change")
   file = open("AddressBook.txt", "r")
   lines = file.readlines()
   for i, line in enumerate(lines):
       if criteria in line:
           for n in range(0,8):
               for lines[i+n]:
                   name = input("Please Provide a full name")
                   if name == "":
                       print("no name detected. Try again")
                       Main()
                       else:
                           f.write(name)
                           f.write("\n")
                           f.write("address: ")
                           f.write(input("Please Give address Line 1"))
                           f.write("\n")
                           f.write("         ")
                           f.write(input("Please Give address line 2"))
                           f.write("\n")
                           f.write("         ")
                           f.write(input("Please Give address line 3"))
                           f.write("\n")
                           f.write("         ")
                           f.write(input("Please Give address line 4"))
                           f.write("\n")
                           f.write("Postcode: ")
                           f.write(input("What is the Postcode?"))
                           f.write("\n")
                           f.write("stdcode: ")
                           f.write(input("What is the Area code?"))
                           f.write("\n")
                           f.write("telephone: ")
                           f.write(input("What is the Telephone number?"))
                           f.write("\n")
                           f.write("\n")
                           f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting there. To change the lines in the file, what you can do is modify the `lines` list directly and then write that out to the file as a string afterwards.

So instead of `f.write`, you would set `lines[i] = input("Please provide full name")` and similarly for all the lines you want to change.

You shouldn't need the two inner `for` loops to do this. As you can just apply the changes sequentially like this:

```
lines[i] = input("Please provide your full name") + '\n'
lines[i + 1] = input("Please provide address line 1") + '\n'
lines[i + 2] = input("Please provide address line 2") + '\n'
lines[i + 3] = input("Please provide address line 3") + '\n'
lines[i + 4] = input("Please provide address line 4") + '\n'
lines[i + 5] = input("Please provide postcode") + '\n'
# and so on
```

Once you've modified the list with all the new data, you can write that entire list out to the file (as a string).

To do this, you need to open the file for writing:

```
f = open("AddressBook.txt", "w")
```

and join the elements of the list to form a string:

```
f.write(''.join(lines))
```

and remember to always close your file:

```
f.close()
```

(Its good practise to also add a `file.close()` after your `file.readlines()`).

This should help you get it working and reduce some of the complexity in your code - especially the over-nesting.